# ANSI C What am I doing wrong with fwrite and the fread?

Tags: c, printf, fwrite, fread

I have the following code in which I attempt to write some data to a file on first execution, and then on second execution reads the file and prints the data to the screen.

In the first execution it writes the data to the screen exactly as it is in the code (`test_data`), and the file is created as expected.

The problem is when I read the file back and write what I have read to the screen it is just the plain contents of the file that I would see in any text editor, and not the original data. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

I'm pretty sure line 67 is at fault, something to do with the way I am printing it to the screen, but I'm very new to C and not used to juggling formats of data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

    FILE * pdataFile = NULL;
    const char * datafilename = "data.bin";
    const char * _WRITE = "wb"; 
    const char * _READ  = "rb"; 
    uint8_t data[32]; 
    int idx; 
    unsigned long dataFileLen; 
    char dataBuffer;

    char test_data[] = "ahFlup1r2PWO1zySK9SBcPIQC5DcCw1mq7JrObea8lDWH&FcLbi7EzBu7ow56KbJ"; 
    char * pos = test_data;



    pdataFile = fopen(datafilename, _READ);
    if (pdataFile == NULL) {
        printf("No existing file named: %s .\n", datafilename);

        /******** Print Contents of data Array ********/
        printf("Random data: "); 

        for (idx = 0; idx < 32; ++idx) {
            sscanf(pos, "%2hhx", &data[idx]);
            pos += 2 * sizeof(char); 
            printf("%02x", data[idx]);  
        };

        printf("\n"); // new line


        /******** Save data to File ********/
        pdataFile = fopen(datafilename, _WRITE);
        if (pdataFile == NULL) {
            printf("Error opening file %s for writing. End Program\n", datafilename); 
        } else {      
            fwrite (test_data, sizeof(char), sizeof(test_data), pdataFile); 

            if (ferror (pdataFile))
                printf("Error writing file %s.", datafilename);     

            fclose (pdataFile);
        };

    } else {
        fseek(pdataFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        dataFileLen = ftell(pdataFile);
        fseek(pdataFile, 0, SEEK_SET);

        char *dataBuffer = malloc((dataFileLen+1)*sizeof(unsigned char));

        fread(dataBuffer, dataFileLen, 1, pdataFile);

        if (ferror (pdataFile))
            {
                printf("Error reading file contents: %s.", datafilename);

            }else{
            printf("data read from file: ");            
            for(idx = 0; idx<dataFileLen; ++idx){ 
                printf("%2hhx", ((char *)dataBuffer)[idx]);  
            };
        };

        printf("\n"); // new line

        fclose (pdataFile);

    };

    return 0;
};
```

**UPDATE** I'm expecting to see the following:
On first execution
`Random data: ahFlup1r2PWO1zySK9SBcPIQC5DcCw1mq7JrObea8lDWH&FcLbi7EzBu7ow56KbJ`

On second execution
`data read from file: ahFlup1r2PWO1zySK9SBcPIQC5DcCw1mq7JrObea8lDWH&FcLbi7EzBu7ow56KbJ`

**Second Update** Even with the answers posted here I am still getting:
`Seed read from file: 6168466c757031723250574f317a79534b39534263504951433544634377266d71374a724f626561286c4457482646634c626937457a4275376f7735264b624a00`

The program is compiled in GCC and should compile from the code here.

Comment: What is your desired output? I see nothing unexpected in your output.

Comment: You're writing the original, text, `test_data` array to disk. You probably mean to say `fwrite (data, sizeof(char), sizeof(data), pdataFile);` instead

Comment: I haven't seen `_READ` or `_WRITE` used as the *mode* parameter to `fopen()`.  Are they defined as `"r"` and `"w"`?

Comment: @wallyk They're assigned at the top of his function.

Comment: @Barmar:  Thanks.  I looked in /usr/include/std*.h instead of in the code.  What a weird thing to do!

Comment: @PaulRoub This writes the data in a legible form, but the second execution is still not correct. I'm getting gaps `data read from file: 6ef8a0b4 51cc7fcbc6e7e 24486c3af8cbd976c173de0fb97b87bead547dff2`

Comment: Probably not the source of the problem but you have way too many semicolons in your code (you don't need them after {} blocks, for example).

Comment: @merlin2011 I just posted an update to answer your question.

Comment: try `printf("%2hhx", ((char *)dataBuffer)[idx]); ` --> `printf("%c", dataBuffer[idx]);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably writing the contents of the wrong array to the file.

Try writing `data` instead of `test_data`.

You will also likely want leading zeros on the values you print when reading the file (just as you already have when you initially print the scanned data).

Comment: Just to clarify for other people I changed which array was written as suggested here and included leading zeros thus: `printf("%02hhx", ((char *)dataBuffer)[idx]); `

Comment: Actually I spoke to soon! This is not the answer because I forgot to erase the file on testing. It should be writing the data from `test_data` and not the data copied into `data`. I know that these should be the same, but the copy was only performed to write out the data in readable format. This won't normally be in finished code.

Comment: Try again.  If you want the output on the second execution to look as you say then you _must_ either `fwrite(data,...)`, or else just `printf("%s", dataBuffer)` with no loop.

Comment: Perhaps your question should also have stated what exactly you expected to find in the data file after the initial run.   :-)  Given you called it a ".bin" file I assumed you wanted it to contain the bytes represented by the hexadecimal values given in the `test_data` string.  If you want it to contain the string itself then obviously all your efforts at converting it in both steps are wasted.